# lapply on single column in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame which I populate from a csv file as follows (**data for sample only**) :

```
> csv_data <- read.csv('test.csv')
> csv_data
  gender country income
1      1      20  10000
2      2      20  12000
3      2      23   3000
```

I want to convert country to factor. However when I do the following, it fails :

```
> csv_data[,2] <- lapply(csv_data[,2], factor)
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , 2, value = list(1L, 1L, 1L)) :
provided 3 variables to replace 1 variables
```

However, if I convert both gender and country to factor, it succeeds :

```
> csv_data[,1:2] <- lapply(csv_data[,1:2], factor)
> is.factor(csv_data[,1])
[1] TRUE
> is.factor(csv_data[,2])
[1] TRUE
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? I want to use lapply since I want to programmatically convert the columns into factors and it could be possible that the number of columns to be converted is only 1(it could be more as well, this number is driven from arguments to a function). Any way I can do it using lapply only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When subsetting for one single column, you'll need to change it slightly.

There's a big difference between

```
lapply(df[,2], factor)
```

and

```
lapply(df[2], factor)
## and/or
lapply(df[, 2, drop=FALSE], factor)
```

Have a look at the output of each.  If you remove the comma, everything should work fine.  Using the comma in `[,]` turns a single column into a vector and therefore each element in the vector is factored individually.  Whereas leaving it out keeps the column as a list, which is what you want to give to `lapply` in this situation.  However, if you use `drop=FALSE`, you can leave the comma in, and the column will remain a list/data.frame.

No good:

```
df[,2] <- lapply(df[,2], factor)
# Warning message:
# In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , 2, value = list(1L, 1L, 1L)) :
#   provided 3 variables to replace 1 variables
```

Succeeds on a single column:

```
df[,2] <- lapply(df[,2,drop=FALSE], factor)
df[,2]
# [1] 20 20 23
# Levels: 20 23
```

On my opinion, the best way to subset data frame columns is without the comma. This also succeeds:

```
df[2] <- lapply(df[2], factor)
df[[2]]
# [1] 20 20 23
# Levels: 20 23
```